# What is the difference between areNotificationsEnabled and areNotificationsPaused

Tags: android, android-notifications

What is the difference between the [areNotificationsEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#areNotificationsEnabled()) and [areNotificationsPaused](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#areNotificationsPaused()) methods in the [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager) class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**areNotificationsEnabled**

The first method, i.e areNotificationsEnabled will be able to tell if the notifications we completely blocked by the user for your app or the package name you want
The user can block the notification in this way

[image: Notification Block]

**areNotificationsPaused**

The second method will be able to tell if the app was snoozed or paused in other terms, that is, a temporary stoppage of notifications from a certain app
The user can snooze notifications from the notification panel by sliding left or right partially and then set the time for which they want the notification to be snoozed

[image: Here you go]

[image: Notification Pause]

Comment: So I should check for areNotificationsEnabled and areNotificationsPaused before launch the notification, Right? Thanks

Comment: I don't do it usually but yes it is a nice practice to alert the user that the notification is blocked, if showing a notification is critical to your app's functionality

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to go through the official docs for the same, it will help you alot, bi

**areNotificationEnabled:-**
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat

```
public boolean areNotificationsEnabled()
```

***Returns whether notifications from the calling package are not blocked.***

**areNotificationPaused:-**
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager

```
public boolean areNotificationsPaused()
```

***Returns whether notifications from this package are temporarily hidden. This could be done because the package was marked as distracting to the user via `PackageManager#setDistractingPackageRestrictions(String[], int)` or because the package is `PackageManager#setPackagesSuspended(String[], boolean, PersistableBundle, PersistableBundle, SuspendDialogInfo)` suspended.***